# CameraX doesn't save the pictures

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camerax

I'm trying to use the example app from google codelabs to implement the camerax application, but i dont know, why it doesnt save the pictures correctly.

```
private fun takePhoto() {
    // Get a stable reference of the modifiable image capture use case
    val imageCapture = imageCapture ?: return

    // Create time-stamped output file to hold the image
    val photoFile = File(
        outputDirectory,
        SimpleDateFormat(
            FILENAME_FORMAT, Locale.GERMAN
        ).format(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"
    )

    // Create output options object which contains file + metadata
    val outputOptions = ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(photoFile).build()

    // Set up image capture listener, which is triggered after photo has
    // been taken
    imageCapture.takePicture(
        outputOptions,
        ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this),
        object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback {
            override fun onError(exc: ImageCaptureException) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Photo capture failed: ${exc.message}", exc)
            }

            override fun onImageSaved(output: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults) {
                val savedUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile)
                val msg = "Photo capture succeeded: $savedUri"
                Toast.makeText(baseContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                Log.d(TAG, msg)
            }
        })
}
```

This is the takePhoto() function which should take and save the photo.

EDIT:

This is the whole code, without imports.

The Emulator is the Pixel 3a XL API 30

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
//CameraX Elements:
private var preview: Preview? = null
private var imageCapture: ImageCapture? = null
private var camera: Camera? = null

//File Elements
private lateinit var outputDirectory: File

//View Elements
//private lateinit var camera_capture_button: Button
private lateinit var cameraExecutor: ExecutorService


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    // Request camera permissions
    if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
        startCamera()
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this, REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS)
    }

    // Set up the listener for take photo button
    camera_capture_button.setOnClickListener { takePhoto() }

    outputDirectory = getOutputDirectory()

    cameraExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
}

private fun takePhoto() {
    // Get a stable reference of the modifiable image capture use case
    val imageCapture = imageCapture ?: return

    // Create time-stamped output file to hold the image
    val photoFile = File(
        outputDirectory,
        SimpleDateFormat(
            FILENAME_FORMAT, Locale.GERMAN
        ).format(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"
    )

    // Create output options object which contains file + metadata
    val outputOptions = ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(photoFile).build()

    // Set up image capture listener, which is triggered after photo has
    // been taken
    imageCapture.takePicture(
        outputOptions,
        ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this),
        object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback {
            override fun onError(exc: ImageCaptureException) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Photo capture failed: ${exc.message}", exc)
            }

            override fun onImageSaved(output: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults) {
                val savedUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile)
                val msg = "Photo capture succeeded: $savedUri"
                Toast.makeText(baseContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                Log.d(TAG, msg)
            }
        })
}

private fun startCamera() {
    val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)

    cameraProviderFuture.addListener(Runnable {
        // Used to bind the lifecycle of cameras to the lifecycle owner
        val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

        // Preview
        val preview = Preview.Builder()
            .build()
            .also {
                it.setSurfaceProvider(viewFinder.surfaceProvider)
            }

        // Select back camera as a default
        val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA

        try {
            // Unbind use cases before rebinding
            cameraProvider.unbindAll()

            // Bind use cases to camera
            cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                this, cameraSelector, preview)

        } catch(exc: Exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Use case binding failed", exc)
        }

    }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
}

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
    requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>, grantResults:
    IntArray) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS) {
        if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
            startCamera()
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                "Permissions not granted by the user.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            finish()
        }
    }
}

private fun allPermissionsGranted() = REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS.all {
    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
        baseContext, it) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
}

private fun getOutputDirectory(): File {
    val mediaDir = externalMediaDirs.firstOrNull()?.let{
        File(it, resources.getString(R.string.app_name)).apply{mkdirs()}}
    return if(mediaDir != null && mediaDir.exists())
        mediaDir
    else
        filesDir
    }

companion object {
    private const val TAG = "CameraXBasic"
    private const val FILENAME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss-SSS"
    private const val REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS = 10
    private val REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS = arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
    }
```

}

The Log after pressing take Photo:

2021-05-25 14:41:23.473 548-1359/system_process I/system_server: oneway function results will be dropped but finished with status OK and parcel size 4

Comment: So you end up with a corupted file? How many bytes?

Comment: No, there is no photo saved. If i press the takePhoto Button in the Emulator, i got no picture in the gallery

Comment: You should not use a Gallery app to check if there is a file. Further you did not tell which Toast you see or what is logged. So we have no idea what is happening or not.

Comment: Ok, in the logs i don't see anything and there is no Toast. I am very new in kotlin so, what can i do?

Comment: Add more logs and or Toast()'s to see what code is executed. Find out if .OnImageSavedCallback () is triggered. As you see no logs it looks as if it is not invoked. Place a Toast() in onError() too as the user should know that too isn't it!

Comment: Further tell the value of `outputDirectory`. And version of used Android device. Put all in your post.

Comment: i tried an other example from this page https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-custom-camera-using-camerax-in-android/ and this works, but i dont know why.

Comment: It seems you aren't initializing imageCapture and not binding it. Is the code you pasted the entire code you're using?

Answer (score 1):

I think I'm a little bit late and you already Figured it out.. It took me a while to find out that in the Codelab ImageCapture had null value so It returns out of takePhoto() on the first line
you suppose to add these in startCamera() just before the Try Block

```
imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder()
                .build()
```

so that you Initialize imageCapture UseCase and then you can start taking photos

P.S. for me it doesn't save pictures on the Emulator but it works fine on real devices.. I'm still working on figuring it out!!
Tested on Xiaomi poco f1 Android 10 and Xiaomi Poco X3 Android 12 and Samsung (don't remember the model) Android 13